# Create a new Winston logger instance on every request

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, winston

I want to create a new instance of Winston logger on every nodejs/express request that is set within a middleware. This is because I want to save on every instance the userId so that is populated in the logs without having to explicitly set every time.

```
const myMiddleware = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
     req.logger = winston.createLogger({
   level: 'info',
   format: winston.format.json(),
   defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service', userId: req.headers['userId'] },
});

     next();
};
```

Is it a bad practice?
What about the memory consumption? Would it be a memory issue assuming you have some the thousands of request per second?

Comment: Creating a new instance of Winston logger for every request may not be the best practice as it can lead to high memory consumption and affect performance, especially when handling large numbers of requests per second. Instead, it's recommended to create a logger instance once and reuse it throughout the application.

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw thanks for your reply. However how can I achieve the defaultData on per request basis so that I don't have to write them every time. ie the userId that I have above.

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw I don't think the Winston instance would be any larger than the other objects that usually get constructed during a request

Answer (score 0):

@spyrAlex I'm thinking of something like this

```js
const winston = require('winston');

// Create a new Winston logger instance with default options
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json()
});

const myMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Add default data to the request object
  req.loggerData = { service: 'user-service', userId: req.headers['userId'] };
  next();
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Log a message with the default data for this request
  logger.log({
    level: 'info',
    message: 'Hello, world!',
    ...req.loggerData
  });
  res.send('Hello, world!');
});
```

Comment: that's a nice idea. I rewrite this using child loggers. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below could also work using a child logger in the request. ie

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
  ]
});

const childLogger = logger.child({ requestId: '451' });

const myMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Add default data to the request object
  req.childLogger = { service: 'user-service', userId: req.headers['userId'] };
  next();
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  req.childLogger({
    message: 'test'
  })
  res.send('Hello, world!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In our use case, we use the logger much deeper integrated and use it inside tons of service classes and utility functions deeper down then in the controler entrypoint.

To make sure that *any* log during the request-response lifecycle (even when not being in the immediate scope of the request) contains the relevant meta attributes it would require

- EITHER forwarding the (child) logger instance created inside the before middleware
- OR forwarding the meta data and programmatically set the meta data through the second log parameter

It would be cumbersome to fiddle either reference through the whole call stack, and it would be much nicer to address this with less code and more systematically.

[`cls-hooked`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-hooked) to the rescue! Here is a schematic breakdown of how I used this neat library for injecting the requestId into the formatter.

./config/logger.ts

```
import cls from 'cls-hooked';

export const loggerNamespace = cls.createNamespace('app-logger')

const requestIdFormatter = format((info: TransformableInfo) => {
  info.requestId = loggerNamespace.get("requestId");

  return info;
});

export default logger = winston.createLogger({
   format: combine(requestIdFormatter(), json())
});
```

./middlewares/RequestContext.ts

```
import { loggerNamespace } from "../config/logger";

export default RequestContext = (req, res, next) => {
  // create a thread-safe context to always access the current requestId
  // The wrapping of middleware's next() inside the run callback, makes sure that the rest of the stack uses the same context
  loggerNamespace.run(() => {
    loggerNamespace.set("requestId", crypto.randomUUID());
    next();
  });
};
```

Now any random helper called inside the middleware stack can log the  randomId.